# Generating Pandigital Numbers

Tags: c#, performance, mathematics

A Base10 Pandigital Number is a number which uses all the digits 0-9 once:

- 1234567890
- 2468013579
- etc...

My naive solution was just to use a bunch of nested loops to do this but it's quite slow. And I'm blanking on a more efficient way to do it? The following takes ~6 seconds.

```
IEnumerable<long> GeneratePandigital()
{
    var other=Enumerable.Range(0,10);

foreach(var a in other)
foreach(var b in other.Except(new int [] {a}))
foreach(var c in other.Except(new int [] {a,b}))
foreach(var d in other.Except(new int [] {a,b,c}))
foreach(var e in other.Except(new int [] {a,b,c,d}))
foreach(var f in other.Except(new int [] {a,b,c,d,e}))
foreach(var g in other.Except(new int [] {a,b,c,d,e,f}))
foreach(var h in other.Except(new int [] {a,b,c,d,e,f,g}))
foreach(var i in other.Except(new int [] {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}))
foreach(var j in other.Except(new int [] {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}))
{
    yield return a * 1000000000L + 
    b * 100000000L+
    c * 10000000L+
    d * 1000000+
    e * 100000+
    f * 10000+
    g * 1000+
    h * 100+
    i * 10+
    j;
}       
}
```

Comment: http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/permutations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to note that each value that is generated will be a permutation of the values `0 - 9`. This will generate `10! = 3628800` possibilities. There are a number of algorithms to generate permutations, the easiest in this case would simply be to generate them in lexicographic order.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Software_implementations) has a rundown of some algorithms you can use to generate permutations.

Comment: *sigh* how did I not spot this... and I actually curate a combinatorics library on Nuget that's perfect for this. http://nuget.org/packages/Combinatorics/ - I blame the early hour. Thanks